# Listing a column from a table to another table's column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find a way where I can list all the exams taken by students in Miami. First here are the tables and data sets. This is the users table:

```
 CREATE TABLE users(
uno NUMBER(5), 
email VARCHAR2(64), 
password VARCHAR2(64), 
fname VARCHAR2 (64) NOT NULL, 
lname VARCHAR2 (64) NOT NULL, 
address1 VARCHAR2 (64), 
address2 VARCHAR2(64), 
city VARCHAR2(64), 
state VARCHAR2(64), 
zip NUMBER(5), 
CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY(uno));
```

users data set:

```
(1,'1@gmail.com','','Mike','Goose','','','Miami','FL','32323')
(2,'2@gmail.com','','Cathy','Vincent','','','Atlanta','GA','91901')
(3,'3@gmail.com','','Steve','McGarth','','','Miami','FL','345321')
```

userResponse table:

```
CREATE TABLE userResponse(
uno NUMBER (5), 
eno NUMBER (5), 
qno NUMBER(5), 
response CHAR (1), 
CONSTRAINT userResponse_pk PRIMARY KEY(uno, eno, qno), 
FOREIGN KEY(uno, eno) REFERENCES enrolls(uno, eno), 
FOREIGN KEY(eno, qno) REFERENCES question(eno, qno)
);
```

userResponse data set:

```
(1,1,1,'A')
(1,1,2,'B')
(1,1,3,'A')
(1,1,4,'B')
(1,1,5,'N')
(1,1,6,'C')
(1,1,7,'D')
(1,1,8,'A')


(2,1,1,'B')
(2,1,2,'B')
(2,1,3,'E')
(2,1,4,'C')
(2,1,5,'D')
(2,1,6,'A')
(2,1,7,'C')
(2,1,8,'B')


(3,1,1,'C')
(3,1,2,'C')
(3,1,3,'D')
(3,1,4,'D')
(3,1,5,'A')
(3,1,6,'A')
```

I know that "uno" have to have some kind of relationship with "city"(for those living in Miami). I'm kind of stuck here because I don't know how I can retrieve two tables together. How do I retrieve the column information from the users table(city) to the column in userResponse table(uno) and how do I list them all? Please let me know. Thanks.

**Edit1:**
I made a mistake here. It's actually all the exams that were taken by the students. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

1) If you want the all the reponse info

```
SELECT *
  FROM userResponses 
WHERE uno IN 
    (
        SELECT uno
          FROM user
         WHERE city = 'MIAMI'
    )
```

2)  If you just want exam no:

```
SELECT DISTINCT eno
  FROM userResponses 
WHERE uno IN 
    (
        SELECT uno
          FROM user
         WHERE city = 'MIAMI'
    )
```

Comment: Oh my bad. It's actually all the exams that were taken by the students. I apologize for that. I got that mixed up lol.